# AppSync Resolver Pipeline - Multiple Outputs Joining

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync, vtl

I have a pipeline resolver that gets data from two datasources sharing the same schema.

Let's say both of them return a list of 10 items each (a total of 20). How can I merge both outputs into one list and return it to AppSync properly as a Json? One is going to be `$context.result` and the other is `$context.prev.result`.

Any methods/functions that can join both of them in VTL (they are of type `List` if I'm not mistaken)?

Edit:
As of now, this is my only solution; doesn't seem efficient as it iterates through the whole list and add it one by one to the other list:

```
#foreach( $item in $context.prev.result )
    $util.qr($context.result.add($item))
#end

$util.toJson($context.result)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

I did not find a "clean" way to solve this problem. I directly edited the final result to merge the lists.

My "After mapping template" :

```
#set( $liste1 = $ctx.prev.result )
#set( $liste2 = $ctx.result )

#set( $strliste1 = $util.toJson($liste1) )
#set( $liste1start = 1 )
#set( $liste1end = $strliste1.length() - 1 )
#set( $newliste1 = $strliste1.substring($liste1start, $liste1end))

#set( $strliste2 = $util.toJson($liste2) )
#set( $liste2start = 1 )
#set( $liste2end = $strliste2.length() - 1 )
#set( $newliste2 = $strliste2.substring($liste2start, $liste2end))

#set( $result = "[$newliste1 , $newliste2]" )
$result
```